# Flutter get Object property Name

Tags: json, object, dart, flutter

I passed the following object:

```
var myVar = { typeA: { option1: "one", option2: "two" } }
```

I want to be able to pull out the key typeA from the above structure.

This value can change each time so next time it could be typeB.

So I would like to know if there is any way to do that

Comment: What exactly is the result that you want? Is it `{ option 1: "one", option2: "two" }`? What have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: I want Object name
``` 
{ typeA: { option1: "one", option2: "two" } , typeB: { option1: "one", option2: "two" } ,typeC: { option1: "one", option2: "two" } }
```
I want TypeA and TypeB and so on

Comment: Sorry, still no idea what the question is about.

Comment: https://api.github.com/users/nitishk72/gists

I want to get the Filename from this URL. This return filename is JSON Object key. What to do ?

Comment: `json[0]['files']['Sum_pointer_object.cpp']['filename']`

Comment: Actually, I have more than 10 gists and I want to access alls filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all filenames you can use:

```
var data = ...
 
var filenames = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[0]['files'];
  var key = item.keys.first;
  var filename = item[key]['filename'];
  filenames.add(filename);
}

print(filenames);
```

Comment: I working with Dart since a long time. I'm still rather new to Flutter.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve using 'keys'

for a json example like this:

```
{
"1-0001": {
  "name": "red",
  "hex": "FF0000"
 },
"1-0002": {
  "name": "blue",
  "hex": "0000FF"
 },
"1-0003": {
  "name": "green",
  "hex": "008000"
 }
}
```

I was able to use

```
Map<String, dynamic> decoded = json.decode(jsonString);
for (var colour in decoded.keys) {
  print(colour);                   // prints 1-0001
  print(decoded[colour]['name']);  // prints red
  print(decoded[colour]['hex']);   // prints FF0000
}
```

Comment: The argument type 'Map<String, Map<String, String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a data type.
It is basically a map of (key value-pair) where key is changed as stated in question typeA or typeB
This Object has 2 properties option1 and option2 which is also strings.

Here is the sample code to construct model and how to use it

```
import 'package:TestDart/TestDart.dart' as TestDart;

main(List<String> arguments) {
  var  map = new Map<String, MyObject>();
  map['typeA'] = new MyObject("one", "two");
  map['typeB'] = new MyObject("one", "two");

  print(map['typeA'].toString());
  print(map['typeA'].toString());
}

class MyObject {
  String _option1;
  String _option2;

  MyObject(this._option1, this._option2);

  String get option2 => _option2;

  String get option1 => _option1;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MyObject{option1: $_option1, option2: $_option2}';
  }


}
```

Relevant answer

```
 map.forEach((key, value) {
    print("Key : ${key} value ${value}");
  });
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted the key name.
I got the correct solution but then also thanks for trying

Comment: i have updated my answer to be more precise and in context of question take a look

Comment: I will try it  and if it works I will definitely accept.